# String helper class

Tags: php, strings

I have class with some basic string operations. Any suggestion to improve the class

```
    class StringHelpers
    {
       function replace_between($str, $needle_start, $needle_end, $replacement) {
          $pos = strpos($str, $needle_start);
          $start = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + strlen($needle_start);

          $pos = strpos($str, $needle_end, $start);
          $end = $start === false ? strlen($str) : $pos;

          return substr_replace($str,$replacement,  $start, $end - $start);
       }

       function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
          $pattern = "/<$tagname>([\w\W]*?)<\/$tagname>/";
          preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
          return $matches[1];
       }

       function checkIfValueContainLetters($value){
          return  preg_match('/[A-Z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+/', $value);
       }

public function createTableRowElementsByValue($bgColor, $tdName, $tdValue)
    {
        $tableRow = '<tr bgcolor="' . $bgColor . '"><td>' . $tdName . '</td><td>' . $tdValue . '</td>  </tr>';
        return $tableRow;
    }

    public function changeBgColorWhiteToBlue()
    {
        if ($this->color == 'D4E4F3') {
            $this->color = '';
            return '';
        }
        $this->color = 'D4E4F3';
        return 'D4E4F3';
    }

    public function createTableRow($tdName)
    {
        return '<td>'. $tdName.'</td>';
    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide some example data, and describe what your code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions do widely different things (replace stuff in a generic string, handle HTML, handle colors, ...), so there are probably better places for them then a generic `StringHelpers` class. A class like this would grow quite large if you handle all functions like this.

`createTableRowElementsByValue` for example doesn't really have anything to do with strings, and `changeBgColorWhiteToBlue` is something else entirely.

- Naming: `checkIfValueContainLetters` is very misleading. I'm not sure if the regex is even correct, since it checks for such an odd thing (definitely a thing too specific for a generic `StringHelpers` class). Did you maybe mean `^[A-Za-z0-9]*$`? Because that would somewhat match your name (except for the numbers). If that's what you want, `isAlphaNumeric` would be a better name.
- Naming: `changeBgColorWhiteToBlue` also doesn't do what it's name suggest. It sets the color to `D4E4F3`, except if it is already `D4E4F3`, in which case it sets it to nothing; there is no white involved.
- Naming: `createTableRow` doesn't create a row (that would be `tr`).
- `getTextBetweenTags` isn't very stable. Input such as `<foo>ba/&!r</foo>`, `foo`, ... would break it.

Comment: Good points. Any suggestions on the gettextbewTweentags

Comment: @DacorieS parsing HTML is hard, and depending on what you need the function for, a regex will not be the right solution (use a HTML parser instead). If it's just for throw-away code or some specific corner-case, try `^<$tagname>(.*)<\/$tagname>$`, and before returning the result, check if there actually was one (but it really depends on your use-case; with this regex for example, there could be tags in your return if they where inside the tagname tag).

Comment: Very true. I  can do some  more validations since I am looking for a  particular value

Answer (score 1):

I haven't code PHP in a while, but some thing can be applied to multiple languages:

1) **parameters checking** - `replace_between` function does not check input parameters. While providing wrong parameter (negative indexes, stop after start etc.) is generating proper exceptions in languages like C# and Java, in PHP may lead to confusing results, as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) when using negative indexes.

2) **(somewhat) ambiguous function name** - `getTextBetweenTags` can be named getFirstTagText, as it seems to get only text found on first provided `$tagname`. Also, `changeBgColorWhiteToBlue` is doing something else (already specified in previous answer)

3) **string formatting** - PHP allows interpolated variables (or interpolated strings as C# calls it), but it [seems to be a little slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676417/should-i-use-curly-brackets-or-concatenate-variables-within-strings). So,

```
'<tr bgcolor="' . $bgColor . '"><td>' . $tdName . '</td><td>' . $tdValue . '</td>  </tr>';
```

becomes something like

```
'<tr bgcolor='$bgColor'><td>'$tdName'</td><td>'$tdValue'</td>  </tr>';
```

Personally, I prefer a (very) little speed downgrade over (much) improved readability.

4) **avoid [magic numbers/strings](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber)** - `D4E4F3` appears three times in your code. I would define a constant for it. Or even better, define css styles and set/unset them.

5) **class name** - `StringHelper` suggests generic string manipulations (like replacing, padding etc.), so only `replace_between` function fits here. A better container name for the rest of the functions would be HtmlHelpers perhaps.

Slightly off-topic, but might be useful: if you need to parse Html content, I advice to take a look into [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Lovely tips. I was unaware of the  interpolated variables and php simple html Dom parser. I will look into them